# Cannot access server running in container from host

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-container

I have a simple Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:latest
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
ENV GOPATH /app
RUN go install huru
EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT /app/bin/huru
```

I build like so:

```
docker build -t huru .
```

and run like so:

```
docker run -it -p 3000:3000 huru
```

for some reason when I go to localhost:3000 with the browser, I get

[image]

I have exposed servers running in containers to the host machine before so not sure what's going on.

Comment: Did you exec into the docker container and test it.

Comment: hmmm well it works outside the container, and the logging looks fine when it runs inside the container, I can verify it's listening on the right port etc

Comment: Does `docker run` logs any errors?(You can even paste entire output, It will help debug the problem) And secondly, how do you exactly start this server (Looking at Dockerfile, at the start of the container  it will be run `/app/bin/huru` without any params)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the information provided in the question if you see logs of the application
(`docker logs <container_id>`) than the docker application starts successfully and it looks like port exposure is done correctly.

In any case in order to see ports mappings when the container is up and running you can use:

```
docker ps
```

and check the "PORTS" section

If you see there something like `0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp`

Then I can think about some firewall rules that prevent the application from being accessed...

Another possible reason (although probably you've checked this already) is that the application starts and finishes before you actually try to access it in the browser.

In this case, `docker ps` won't show the exited container, but `docker ps -a` will.

The last thing I can think of is that in the docker container itself the application doesn't really answer the port 3000 (I mean, maybe the startup script starts the web server on some other port, so exposing port 3000 doesn't really do anything useful).

In order to check this you can enter the docker container itself with something like `docker exec -it <container_id>` bash

and check for the opened ports with `lsof -i`  or just `wget localhost:3000` from within the container itelf

Comment: yeah `docker ps` is giving me `0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp`, so yeah idk

Comment: I think it might be a golang thing, there shouldn't be a firewall problem tmk, the logs coming out of the container show that the golang code works and the golang server is running in the container and listening on the right port.

Comment: listening on "0.0.0.0" instead of "localhost" made it work! lol fml, why??? I wish I knew more about networking

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, if this has any output log. Please check them...

```
FROM golang:latest
RUN apt -y update
RUN mkdir -p /app
COPY . /app
RUN go install huru
WORKDIR /app

docker build -t huru:latest .
docker run -it -p 3000:3000 huru:latest bin/huru
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this url: http://127.0.0.1:3000
I use the loopback